# How to save a more complex object like a Car (with sub-object, like Tiers, with sub-objects like Rims, ...) to Google Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase

I searched for this across the internet. But no answer.
I have a fairly complex object:

```
public class Goal {

 private String label;
 private Date endDate;
 private LinkedList<SubGoal> gListSubGoals;
 private LinkedList<Task> gListTasks;
}
```

It has members that are Arrays of other Objects, like Sub-Goals. And Each subgoal has its own label, title, dateStart, dateEnd.

How do I save such an object to Google Firebase?
I only found information about simpler object with ints, and String, but nothing that is 3-levels of composition deep.

Maybe you have a snippet of code, a link with an example. Anything, please.

Comment: Firebase offers two solutions and depending on what you need you can choose to go with json or collections. Here is a link to the documentation that explains the difference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rtdb-vs-firestore

Comment: @rene: It says this: Realtime Database
Stores data as one large JSON tree. Simple data is very easy to store. Complex, hierarchical data is harder to organize at scale. While at the same: CLOUD_FIRESTORE: Stores data in documents organized in collections.
Simple data is easy to store in documents, which are very similar to JSON.
Complex, hierarchical data is easier to organize at scale, using subcollections within documents. Requires less denormalization and data flattening. I asume they encourage FIRESTONE for what I an looking for?

Comment: Exactly, not sure how deep your data goes, but it sounds like it

Comment: it is about 3-4 levels. Do you know where I can find a full on tutorial how to integrate Firebase Authentification with Saving to Firestore?